# How to call Firebase Cloud Function directly from you angular project

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am new to firebase and is trying to understand how to call a firebase cloud function directly from my angular app. I have previously used angularfire2 for doing Firebase stuff but it seems that angularfire2 does not have support for cloud functions so now I am left lost and does not know how to do it.

I have looked at the documentation but I can not really understand how, exactly, I am supposed to call the cloud function from one of my *service.ts* files. The example from [Firebase Doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable) is displayed below. **I wonder how I get the *"functions"* reference within one of my angular *service.ts* files?**

```
functions.httpsCallable("addMessage").call(["text": inputField.text]) { (result, error) in
  if let error = error as NSError? {
    if error.domain == FunctionsErrorDomain {
      let code = FunctionsErrorCode(rawValue: error.code)
      let message = error.localizedDescription
      let details = error.userInfo[FunctionsErrorDetailsKey]
    }
    // ...
  }
  if let text = (result?.data as? [String: Any])?["text"] as? String {
    self.resultField.text = text
  }
}
```

Do I need to import something in the app.module.ts file or what am I supposed to do?

Any help is much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#set_up_your_client_development_environment ? See the web-tab. You can do `var addMessage = firebase.functions().httpsCallable('addMessage');
addMessage({text: messageText}).then(function(result) {
  // Read result of the Cloud Function.
  var sanitizedMessage = result.data.text;
  // ...
});` in your .ts files since typescript is just a superset of javascript.

Comment: y. I understand your answer. Though I have not managed to import the correct thing in order to reference "firebase" in firebase.functions()......

Comment: In other words: I am getting: [ts] cannot find name 'firebase'. So my question becomes: What do I need to import in order to reference firebase?

Comment: @Phil do you know what I need to import? :)

Comment: for non-angular modules you need to use require: `const firebase = require("firebase");`. For an example see here: https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/tools/gulp/util/firebase.ts

Comment: still running into this issue 2019

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maintainer here, Angularfire shipped the AngularFireFunctions module in RC 9 the other day. [See the AngularFire changelog entry here.](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/releases/tag/5.0.0-rc.9)

Note that as of RC 8, you'll need to upgrade to at least Firebase 5.0.2 and rxjs 6. rxjs-compat will help it you still have dependencies on rxjs 5.

Comment: Great! I downloaded new version for AngularFire. Imported the AngularFireFunctions and updated Firebase, rxjs. Works just fine! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this issue as well and the answer from James didn't really answer my question on where I could find a good example on how it would look in Angular. However, within the firebase repostiory [a README with small, but enough documentation can be found](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/functions/functions.md).

This is pretty much how compact you can go:

```js
import { AngularFireFunctions } from '@angular/fire/compat/functions';

constructor(
    private fns: AngularFireFunctions
  ) {}

  addMessage(): Observable<any> {
    const addMessage = this.fns.httpsCallable('addMessage'); 
    return addMessage({text: "test"});
  }
```